# Is there a way to get an identifier from a physical keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bluetooth, keyboard-wedge

I need to identify some hardware keyboards connected via bluetooth to my app.

I have it connected via bluetooth and I can access to it via `GCKeyboard.coalesced`; I know that it comes from class `GCKeyboard` that implements `GCDevice` and I cannot get an unique identifier of the device currently connected: I only can get the vendorName and product category that only returns "Keyboard".

I also tried to get the bluetooth device but that keyboard is not BLE and neither is MFi compliant.

Is there a turnaround that I could do?